# Why could the Tendo control the weather?

Tags: naruto

Does anyone know why the Tendo Path of Pain apparently had control over the weather at some point? After he detects Jiraiya the power isn't ever mentioned again. The two shinobi Jiraiya captures talk about the weather as if "Lord Pain" prevents it, but in the translation I read, Pain says "Someone has circumvented my rain," as if he causes it. Regardless of whether Pain controls the rain, is there a plausible explanation for how this could be?

Comment: Remember the thing is made from nature chakra

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by one of the techniques pain Nagato uses the [Rain tiger at will technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rain_Tiger_at_Will_Technique). This technique infused with chakra causes the user to sense outsiders chakra

> when guarding Amegakure Nagato was able to use the **Rain Tiger at Will Technique** to make it rain. This rain was infused with his chakra and as such, served as a large-scale sensory technique for him in his village.

The description of this technique would be

> A perception ninjutsu, allowing one to freely manipulate rain infused with the user's own chakra. The rain falls from rain clouds, formed with Pain's own chakra. During this technique, the falling raindrops are closely linked to Pain's senses. When the rain is obstructed by a chakra belonging to someone not of the village, the existence of the intruder can be detected. The rain will keep on falling until Pain uses the seal to cancel it. Pain made it rain every Sunday in Amegakure, or whenever he had to leave the village.

Comment: While this clears up what the jutsu was, I was more looking for how that path could use more than just his telekinetic abilities. A major plot point was that they could only use one jutsu. Is this just a plot hole?

Comment: @RamseyYunis Might just be your mis conception. There are 6 paths of pain. And we have Nagato, the user himself. so it is not one of pains paths that is causing this rain. but rather Nagato himself ( the one that also had the rebirth technique)